# Confirming my answer to this small signal analysis exam question

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, analog, cmos, differential-amplifier

[image: Schematic]

This question wants a common mode gain by using small signal analysis. Can you check this solution I'm not sure about my answer and what should I do if it's wrong.

[image: Pic3]

[image: Pic2]